# How to change background color of cardview for 5 seconds and revert into its previous color

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to change background color of card view for 5 seconds when coming from an specific activity. 
Its a cardview of recyclerview.
But app getting crash. I tried handler but not able to rid off.

```
 if (intent.hasExtra("post_Id")) {
        postId = intent.getIntExtra("post_Id", 0)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            post_card_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E1F2F878"))
        }, 1000)
    }
```

Comment: share your codes please

Comment: @majidghafouri done, its changing color but how to stop handler so that cardview go in previous color

Comment: use timers.....

Comment: As @RonTLV suggested, Instead of the `Handler` a Timer is a lot more convenient. Checkout **`CountDownTimer`**.

Comment: what about second handler for 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your code to that:

```
Handler().postDelayed({
        post_card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E1F2F878"))
    }, 1000)
Handler().postDelayed({
        post_card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(previous color)
    }, 6000)
```

or if you dont need delay for first change just:

```
Handler().post {
        post_card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E1F2F878"))
    }
Handler().postDelayed({
        post_card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(previous color)
    }, 5000)
```

Comment: it is should stop by itself once it finished run operation in runnable.

Comment: can you please show me the sample code it would be more helpful for me and also optimised

Comment: Code is above in response. First Handler is "registered" to run your operation in 1 second. Then second Handler is "registered" to run your operation in 6 seconds (5 seconds after first one). After operation in 1-st handler is done - Handler is "unregistered". The same for second.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **`CountDownTimer`** class which will perform count-down.

Check-out the **Kotlin** snippet:

```
private const val COUNT_DOWN_TIME = 5secs   
private const val COUNT_DOWN_TIME = 1sec   

 class TimeCounter : CountDownTimer(val COUNT_DOWN_TIME,val COUNT_DOWN_INTERVAL) {

        override fun onFinish() {

          // This method will be called after completion of COUNT_DOWN_TIME
          // Do your work here once the limit of 5secs is completed.

        }


        override fun onTick(timeLeftUntilFinish: Long) {

            //this method is called every COUNT_DOWN_INTERVAL, until the timer is finished
//So if COUNT_DOWN_INTERVAL = 1sec, this method is called every 1sec till the timer is completed.

        }

    }
```

You can implement it within the parent `Activity` as an inner class or can declare it independently as per your need.

Since you implemented it, **you are completely responsible for starting the timer**

Starting the **`CountDownTimer`** :

param1 :COUNT_DOWN_TIME // the time for which you wanna count-down

param2 :COUNT_DOWN_INTERVAL // the time after every which you get notified until count-down

```
val mTimer = CountDownTimer(COUNT_DOWN_TIME ,COUNT_DOWN_INTERVAL ) //create Timer Instance
mTimer.start()  //start the timer
```

However, **stoping the timer has two ways**

1. The count-down expires as normal ( you have successfully counted for
   5 secs)
2. You cancel the timer on your own for some reasons.

For cancelling the **`CountDownTimer`**:

```
mTimer.cancel() // stops Timer as soon as called, irrespective whether count-down was pending.
```

**Note: This goes without saying but still, use the same object for starting and stoping the timer.**